# How to query $near in CosmosDB via mongoDB protocol

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-cosmosdb

I have this document

```
{
    "_id" : "8cbc4fdc79d5479c95deaab471d359bb",
    "category" : "test",
    "location" : {
        "name" : "Café Café",
        "coordinates" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                34.788589, 
                32.0857813
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And this query returns 0 records on CosmosDB, but works as expected on real mongoDB

```
db.activities.find({'location.coordinates': { $near :{$geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ 34.788589, 32.0857813 ] }}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

$geoNear is now supported in Azure Cosmos DB: MongoDB API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-36#aggregation-stages

Comment: If you consider your post to be a comment please delete it. Or [edit] it into an answer according to [answer]. Because it is intentional that commenting needs a certain reputation. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead and you seem to actually be aware of that.

Comment: Wow @Yunnosch, thank you for being supportive to a new member of the community.

Comment: Can we cooperate with each other? I would like to help you clear your misunderstanding or maybe the wrong impression your comment gives. You do see that your comment might be perceived as "I know the rules of this community, ignore them intentionally and misuse an answer post for commenting, which by those rules I am not yet supposed to do.", don't you? The post itself can be seen as an answer, not necessarily a comment. But the point is that if you yourself consider it the kind of comment that you are not yet allowed, then your misunderstanding should be fixed. At least delete the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, if I use `$near` in a query, as you said, it returns 0 records on Azure Cosmos DB.

[image]

As far as I know, not all of MongoDB's query syntax / capabilities are implemented in Azure Cosmos DB: MongoDB API. if possible, you can open a feedback item on [Azure Cosmos DB User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api) and track updates.

Comment: And ``$geoNear`` seems not supported yet.